# What is the best way of doing multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  funcA(i);
  funcB(i);
}
```

I want to implement it using multi-threads, and i think there are two ways to do so (in both, each thread takes a sub-range of [0, n]):

1) Create a thread class that executes both functions.

2) Create two thread classes: the first executes funcA() and the second executes funcB(), such as each one has its own loop, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  funcA(i);
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  funcB(i);
}
```

Which one is the best? or are they equivalent?

Comment: You forgot a semi-colon for `funcB(i)`.

Comment: As just from the title: Cautiously!

Comment: @g-makulik: Reminds me of Tom Lehrer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4KybdSi1Fc

Comment: Have a look at OpenMP.  If your platform supports it, may save you lots of time & trouble; also nice/easy to try different strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider the TBB library (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which uses task-based parallelism to even out possible differences in the execution time of individual iterations. Your code would look like this (using C++11)

```
tbb::parallel_for(0,n,[](int i){
  funcA(i);
  funcB(i);
});
```

You can also use C++03, when you must replace the lambda with an ordinary functor. With TBB you can also code it as a pipeline.

Alternatively, with OpenMP, your code is simply

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) {
  funcA(i);
  funcB(i);
}
```

but this requires your compiler to support OpenMP (clang doesn't), which doesn't mesh well with C++11.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on whether the functions are inter-dependent.

If the execution of one does not depend on any variables affected by the other, you are free and even encouraged to execute both functions in separate threads.

But if there are some execution order dependencies, beware. You can use mutexes to avoid some problems, but it might be better to execute them sequentially.

**EDIT:** As you have stated in comments, execution of `funcB(i)` depends on `funcA(i)`, however `{funcA(i); funcB(i)}` blocks are independent on each other.

You can then execute multiple of those in parallel by partitioning the (0,n] range to k threads

Comment: funcB depends from funcA

Comment: In my opinion then, the sequential execution would be better, as it would save some synchronization overhead.

Comment: it's an image analysis program, and i need to accelerate the execution

Comment: As I have said, if the execution of funcB depends on results of funcA, you cannot parallelize using the second approach. However, if you can execute say thread1 = {funcA(1); funcB(1)} and thread2 = {funcA(2); funcB(2)} in any order, then by all means, use that method of parallelization.

Comment: @WildThing You can accelerate execution that way, for cases either one thread may block on OS operations (e.g. IO operations over slow devices or network connections), or you can split complete processing steps to be executed on one of more CPU cores available.

Comment: funcB(i) depends only on funcA(i), it doen not depend on funcA(i-1) or funcA(i+1) etc. so it is possible to compute funcA for all i values then compute funcB for all i values too.

Comment: @WildThing This would fit the second scenario I have mentioned. It will help only with multiple cores available on the specific machine, and you have to synch and merge on all the results (I would have each thread execute it's own loop).

Comment: *As I have said, if the execution of funcB depends on results of funcA, you cannot parallelize using the second approach.* **WRONG**. This is possible, as long as the data are processed in order. This is called a *pipeline* and is typical of data processing.

Answer (score 1):

From the two approaches you provided the second one would be better.

**Reason:** the first approach implies you are making `n` threads to execute each loop, whereas the second approach is creating two threads and assigning one to work on `funcA` whilst the other words on `funcB`. Then once they have completed, continue to the next iteration and repeat. This is a much better approach as you have two threads working towards a common goal rather than `n` threads.

Comment: i dont make n thread to execute each loop. i said that every thread executes a sub-range of [0,n]