# Data sharing in openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, private, sharing

In writing multithreaded programs, the default is data sharing memory among all threads, and one needs to specify what is private. Is it possible to declare all data as private?

Regards,
-Mohd

Comment: Data types declared outside a parallel block are shared (unless it's an index in a parallel loop) and those declared inside a parallel block are private.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500301/use-openmp-to-find-minimum-for-sets-in-parallel-c/18512800#18512800)

Comment: Great link, thank you, I wanted to do some multithreading to my program without changing the code much, it seems that this is not possible.

Comment: Post the code you're trying to parallelize (try and make it readable and not too long).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [thread local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).

Answer (score 0):

You can, [for example](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c):

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int nthreads, tid;

/* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
  {

  /* Obtain thread number */
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

  /* Only master thread does this */
  if (tid == 0) 
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }

  }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

}
```

However, you cannot replace shared data with asynchronous messages as openmp tasks are not guaranteed to run asynchonously:

[Use Threads Correctly = Isolation + Asynchronous Messages](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/use-threads-correctly-isolation-asynch/215900465)

Comment: I wanted to do this without specifying what identifiers are private. I expected some command is available to do this (private data) declaration.

Comment: [Memory can be declared as private in two ways](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-with-openmp). The second is to declare the variable inside the loop (i.e inside the parallel OpenMP directive) without the static keyword.

Comment: can you comment on where does nthreads resides? stack or heap?